# Get the Order ID in Woocommerce order received page as shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, orders

I want to have WooCommerce Order ID's referenced as a shortcode to be easily be used in the Order received page to generate dynamic links.

```
function my_order_id( $atts ) {
    echo $order->get_id();
}
add_shortcode( 'my_order_id', 'my_order_id');
```

Comment: Write more details what are you looking for?

Comment: First of all in a shortcode you do not `echo` but `return`.  Where is this shortcode going to be used? In the checkout page? To show other orders?

Comment: That is simply NOT possible as **Order ID doesn't exist in checkout**, It's generated only after customer has "placed order"…

Comment: @OmarTanti I want to have it in the order-received page, so the transaction has been approved, and the Order ID has been generated. But I want to dynamically name files on S3 with the same Order ID to keep files consistent, and shortcodes can function within URL parameters.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec This is in the order-received, so the transaction has been approved.

Comment: @brandonthebuck That was not clear, so I have updated your question and answered…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the way to get the Order ID in "Order received" (thankyou) page as a shortcode:

```
function get_order_id_thankyou( $atts ) {
    // Only in thankyou "Order-received" page
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) )
        return; // Exit

    global $wp;

    // Get the order ID
    $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );

    if ( empty($order_id) || $order_id == 0 )
        return; // Exit;

    // Testing output (always use return with a shortcode)
    return '<p>Order ID: ' . $order_id . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_order_id', 'get_order_id_thankyou');
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

The same for the **order key**:

```
function get_order_key_thankyou( $atts ) {
    // Only in thankyou "Order-received" page
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) )
        return; // Exit

    global $wp;

    // Get the order ID
    $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );

    if ( empty($order_id) || $order_id == 0 )
        return; // Exit;

    // Testing output (always use return with a shortcode)
    return '<p>Order Key: ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_order_key', true ) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_order_key', 'get_order_key_thankyou');
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! Can this be modified to display the order_key?

Comment: @brandonthebuck Added an additional code for that after…

Comment: Brilliant! Great!! 
I searched for `$wp->query_vars['order-received']` for ages!! @LoicTheAztec, where did you get this?

in any case - thank you so muuch!!

Comment: would $wp->query_vars['order-received'] always be order-received, if you changed the endpoint name would this be the customised end point name instead?

Comment: Does this work even if the slug was translated using WPML for instance?

Comment: @alev Meta key should not be translated!… instead use `__()` function when saving the value. Then you will be able to translate the value as a translatable string.